# How do you know the current version of the Bamboo REST API?

Tags: rest, bamboo

I've written a small application which accesses the [REST API of Atlassian Bamboo](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/rest-apis/).

As the [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/using-the-bamboo-rest-apis/#api-versions) describes:

> To get the latest version of the API, you can also use the `latest` key-word.

So I used the `latest` keyword to access the version. But I noticed now, after migrating to the new Bamboo version, that this wasn't the best solution, because the new version seems to have changed some things in the API and breaks my application.

Now I would like to build my application with a specific API version. But how can I tell: which is the exact version of the current API?

The only thing which the documentation is saying about this:

> - The API version is independent of the Bamboo release number.
> - The API version may, or may not, change with a new Bamboo release. The API  version number will change only when the updates to the API break the API contract, requiring changes in the code which uses the API. ...

The documentation of the single Bamboo versions (like [the one for 6.6.2](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/REST/6.6.2/)) only uses the `latest` keyword as reference.

And even the REST api itself (under `/rest/api/latest/info`) only tells me the Bamboo version, not the API version:

```
<info>
<version>6.6.2</version>
<edition/>
<buildDate>2018-08-14T09:01:47.000+02:00</buildDate>
<buildNumber>60606</buildNumber>
<state>RUNNING</state>
</info>
```

So how do I find the exact API version of my Bamboo installation?

Comment: You could use the fact that you know the API breaks in one version but not in the other - if it's a GET api call...

Comment: But that's exactly the problem - I don't know what will break in the future. And as Atlassian has [a guideline](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/atlassian-rest-api-design-guidelines-version-1/) that the REST API should support at least  two versions, I guess I'm much safer if I use the _current_ version instead of `latest`. But as I don't know the current version, I can't do that.

Comment: I think you can safely assume that the api is tied to the Bamboo version.  So, with each new Bamboo version, you can test your code and adjust it as necessary and then conditionalize on the version you get back from the info api

Comment: I think you don't get the point: I don't want to adjust my application every time a new Bamboo version is released (which happens quite often). I only want to do that, when my API version is not supported anymore (which happens rarely). What's the point in having a versioned API if you can't use it?

Comment: I understand. I suggest you see if you can get anywhere with Atlassian Support. Good luck.